# Completness of norm in $L_\infty$

Tags: measure-theory

How can I prove that $L_\infty$ is a complete space with the following standard norm?

$||f||_\infty=\inf\{M\in\mathbb{R}^+:|f(x)|\leq M\text{ a.e.}\}$

This proof is left to the reader in the text I'm following, but it does not give any hint on how the proof should be carried out.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Keen-ameteur I know how to prove the completness of $L_p$ for $1\leq p<\infty$, but the fact that this proof was left to the reader makes me think it must be much easier. So far, I'm not coming up with any useful ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you need to work with the definition of a complete space. i.e., take a Cauchy sequence $\{ f_n \}_{n=1}^\infty$ w.r.t $\Vert \cdot \Vert_ {L^\infty}$, find a limit function $f$ and show that $\Vert f_n-f\Vert_{L^\infty}\to 0$.

As a **hint**, consider the set

$$ E:=\Big \{ x: \underset{n\to \infty}{\lim} f_n(x) \; \text{exists} \Big\},   $$
and define

$$ f(x)=\begin{cases} \underset{n\to \infty}{\lim} f_n(x) & , x\in E\\
0 & , x\notin E \end{cases} $$

Now show that $\mu(E^c)=0$, and that for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists $N_\epsilon$ such that

$$ \vert f_n(x)-f(x)\vert <\epsilon \quad \text{for all} \quad n>N_\epsilon \quad \text{and} \quad x\in E. $$

Recall also that

$$E = \{ x: \big( f_n(x) \big)_{n=1}^\infty \; \text{is a Cauchy seq.} \Big\}. $$

Answer (score 1):

Some ideas: (not a complete solution but too long for a comment)

Do you know the fact that the infimum in your definition is actually a minimum? You can find a set $A$ of measure 0 so that $\|f\|_{\mathcal{L}^\infty} = \|f|_{X\setminus A}\|_\infty$ with the classical uniform norm.
Next you can look at an arbitrary absolute convergent series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\|[f_n]\|_{L^\infty} < \infty$ of functions $[f_n] \in L^\infty$ and try to show that this series converges in $L^\infty$ (a space is Banach iff absolute convergent series are convergent). Now you can use the previous fact, that the infimum is a minimum, together with the fact that the space of all bounded functions is a Banach space (giving you convergence of the series a.e. since countable unions of sets of measure 0 have measure 0).